# Unexpected token { cuando intento importar una variable en Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose

Estoy siguiendo una documentación y copiando el mismo código me da error este import en `app.js`

app.js:

```js
/*
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
*/
// Aquí me da el error:
import models, { connectDatabase } from './models/IndexModels'
/*
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT;
app.use(cors())

connectDatabase().then(async () => {
    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`database up and express app running on port ${port}`))
})
*/
```

También he probado a simplemente poner: `import { connectDatabase } from './models/IndexModels'` y me da el mismo error:

```
import { connectDatabase } from './models/IndexModels'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Este es el archivo desde donde exporto:

IndexModels.js:

```js
/*
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import List from "./list"
import Task from "./task"
import User from "./user"

const connectDatabase = () => {
    return mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
}
*/

const models = { List, Task, User };

export { connectDatabase }
export default models;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) es el sistema usado por `Node.js` para el trabajo con módulos, tu código está usando [módulos nativos de ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import) y estos no son soportados todavía por `Node.js`. Si el código es para trabajar directamente en `Node.js` intenta importar los módulos de la siguiente forma:

```
const IndexModels = require('./models/IndexModels');
const { models, connectDatabase } = IndexModels;
```

Y exportarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
module.exports = {models, connectDatabase};
```

Otra solución es usar [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm), instálalo:

```
npm install esm -g
```

Y después puedes ejecutar el código que trabaja con módulos `ES6` de la siguiente manera:

```
node -r esm tufichero.js
```

O si tienes `Node 13`, podrías usar [una de sus funciones experimentales](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (trabajar con módulos `ES6`). Renombra el fichero de `js` a `mjs` y ejecuta:

```
node --experimental-modules tufichero.mjs
```

Comment: Es una oviedad, pero faltaría aclarar que nodejs aún no soporta esa sintáxis de ES6.

Comment: @emeeus, lo aclaro ;)